# Navigate to Symbol in XCode 8

Tags: ide, xcode8

In XCode 7 it was possible to navigate to symbol/object i.e. pressing

```
⌘ + ⇧ + O
```

And typing
    didFinishLau...

Resulted in possibility to navigation to suitable method in AppDelegate file. Recently, after updating to XCode 8 I've found this option missing, is there any possibility to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8 when you select Edit -> Emoji & Symbols you get (I think by default) this smaller Special Chars tool.
To get access to the more familiar view with a search select the icon in the top right.
[Xcode 8 Emoji & Symbols chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpgFf.png)

Then you get the familiar one.
[Symbol chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stES6.png)

Hope it's helpful to you.